# Why $\sum_{i = j}^\infty\frac{i!}{(i-j)!\cdot j!}\cdot k^{i-j}\cdot (1-k)^j = 1/(1-k)$?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

$$
\sum_{i = j}^\infty\frac{i!}{(i-j)!\cdot j!}\cdot k^{i-j}\cdot (1-k)^j = \frac1{1-k}
$$
I take this equal than I do some problem of probabiliti teory. I think that it will be prove by indukcia, but I can't.

Comment: I have edited your expression using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Could you please check it to see if I did any mistakes. And for next time, consider using it yourself; it makes formulas much easier to read.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that k is probability. So it is 0<k<1.

Comment: @AndreyKomisarov It is not clear what you mean. Please check if it is the following one: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=i}^{\infty}  {i \choose j}\cdot  k^{i-j}\cdot (1-k)^j$.

Comment: @callculus No, j is a constant, the suming is only by i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it helps to write $i=j+l$, then divide out $(1-k)^j$ to restate the claim as $\sum_{l\ge 0}\binom{j+l}{j}k^l=(1-k)^{-j-1}$. This is just a special case of the binomial theorem, since the falling Pochhammer symbol $(-j-1)_l=\binom{j+l}{j}(-1)^l$.